# opening a file > replacing text in a loop in unix

Tags: linux, loops, unix, awk, sed

I have a file abc.csv which is as follows;-

```
sn,test,control
1,file1,file2
2,file3,file4
```

i have another configuration file text.cfg as follows:-

```
model.input1 = /usr/bin/file1
model.input2 = /usr/bin/file2
```

now i want to replace the file1 and file2 with
file3 and file4 respectively and then
file5 and file6 and so on,, till the abc.csv file is exhausted

my attempt for the problem is :-

```
IFS =","

while read NUM TEST CONTROL


X=""
Y=""

do
    echo "Serial Number :$NUM"
    echo "Test File :$TEST"
    echo "Control File:$CONTROL"

    sed -i -e 's/$A/$B/g' text.cfg

    X = $TEST
    Y = $CONTROL

done < abc.csv
```

the ouput should be new config files as follows:-

this is the `test1.cfg`:

```
model.input1 = /usr/bin/file1
model.input2 = /usr/bin/file2
```

then the second file should be `test2.cfg`

```
model.input1 = /usr/bin/file3
model.input2 = /usr/bin/file4
```

and so on..

Comment: It would be useful if you also showed us the exact output you expect from the input you've shown. Please [edit] your question to do so.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: I need to change the test.cfg file by looping through every line in the abc.csv file and changing the file names as given in the abc.csv file line by line

Comment: Things like `IFS =","` are wrong, you should paste your script in www.shellcheck.net to clear these errors and then focus on the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{i = 0; while(++i < NF){print "model.input"i" = /usr/bin/"$(i+1) >> "test"$1".cfg"} }' File
```

Output:

```
AMD$ cat test1.cfg
model.input1 = /usr/bin/file1
model.input2 = /usr/bin/file2
AMD$ cat test2.cfg
model.input1 = /usr/bin/file3
model.input2 = /usr/bin/file4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is what i needed!!